# How to show git log for only two branches?

Tags: git

I want to browse git history (in bash terminal) of only specific git branches. This scenario is pretty frequent use case, because people do want to compare their "feature" branch with the "master" branch.

Naively, I tried:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --branches=feature/my_cool_feature
```

But even in this case I see all the other branches.

Can anyone help with the git command (in bash terminal) to show the graph of git history for only the specified branches?

Comment: It's not trivial. In git, a branch is a pointer to a commit, git log will display all of the commits that have an ancestry path to the top branch commit (hence why it goes all the way back). You'd have to limit the range for `git log` by finding the fork point for the branch.

Comment: Would `master...featurebranch` work? It will show all commits reachable from master AND from featurebranch, but exclude those that are reachable from both branches (in other words: exclude common/uninteresting history)

Comment: What's wrong with `git log --oneline --decorate --graph master feature`?

Answer (score 7):

The command

```
git show-branch feature master
```

will show commits that only exist in either master or feature but not both.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is the command you're looking for.

`git log --oneline --graph --decorate somebranch otherbranch`

Comment: This still shows all the branches, instead of just these two

Comment: it shows branch names only for commits in the requested history that happen to be other branches

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
git log --first-parent --graph --decorate 21547ed HEAD
```

I don't know when `--first-parent` appeared, or whether it's exactly right, but it cuts out 2899827383 vertical ASCII art lines.